# Kubuntu 19.10 and Lightworks 14.6

Tags: video-editor

I would like to install [Lightworks 14.6](https://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&func=view&catid=19&id=199690&Itemid=81) (latest release) in Kubuntu 19.10. Can you please advise how I should go about it? I am new to Linux world, hence this basic question. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no support for 19.10 yet; as per https://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&func=view&catid=19&id=199690&Itemid=81 and https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Lightworks-14.6-Beta-2 . The latest Ubuntu family OS they support is 19.04.

Comment: If this answered your question, you may click on the up arrowhead and the checkmark to the left of the answer to show others this provided useful information and was the best answer (respectively).